# Upload files by post to server OutOfMemory

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I'm developing a remote backup app, and Sometimes I need upload big files as for example 15 MB, I have tested in some phones I get an out of memory error

Is there a way to use less memory using this function?

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                /*   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);*/
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
              // String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

              // Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                //     + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {


                            /*messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            //  ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      /*messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");*/
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              //e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      //messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
         // dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }
```

Here the error log

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:218)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$DefaultHttpOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:750)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:101)
at com.androidexample.uploadtoserver.UploadToServer.a(SourceFile:151)
at com.androidexample.uploadtoserver.e.run(SourceFile:62)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

After modify and add Fixed no Buffer i get this error

```
Exception : expected 589715 bytes but received 589840
java.io.IOException: expected 589715 bytes but received 589840
at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.write(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:39)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
at com.androidexample.uploadtoserver.UploadToServer.uploadFile(UploadToServer.java:152)
at com.androidexample.uploadtoserver.UploadToServer$1.run(UploadToServer.java:62)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I guess this bytes of difference are the headers data right? how can I get the length() of the headers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use either the `setChunkedStreamingMode()` or `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()` methods of the HttpURLConnection. This will prevent the buffering of your data in memory and exhausting it.

Relevant quote from the documentation:

> For best performance, you should call either
>   setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int) when the body length is known in
>   advance, or setChunkedStreamingMode(int) when it is not. Otherwise
>   HttpURLConnection will be forced to buffer the complete request body
>   in memory before it is transmitted, wasting (and possibly exhausting)
>   heap and increasing latency.

More here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Can you help me with an example? I'm java Newbie, and really I did not found in google any example how to make that and how to know the body lengh before post data. Thanks Aves

Comment: just like @Caner said above, all you have to do is call the method like so:
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);

Comment: Hi Aves, thanks for your reply, but When I set conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize); my file not arrive to my server.

Comment: @aves: using `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()` do we get complete file at server end not in chunks?

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(sourceFile.length());
```

below:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: Hi Caner, Any idea how can I see the difference between memory used in the app with setFixedLengthStreamingMode vs Without? How can I test in eclipse or if there is an other way to know real memory usage please. Thanks!

Comment: Use DDMS. It is explained here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: Enable it first: From Eclipse: Click Window > Open Perspective > Other... > DDMS.

Comment: This way `HttpURLConnection` will handle buffering and send your data in chunks. Previously it was buffering whole 15MB and trying to send at once.

Comment: I tried to do that and I get an error, I just edited the question bottom with the logcat output

Comment: Alternatively you can try `conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);`

Comment: convert `sourceFile.length()` in int `conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int)sourceFile.length());`