# OutOfMemoryError when reading a large Text Files

Tags: android, memory-leaks, arraylist, android-asynctask, out-of-memory

My application has a function to read a text file from the SD card, when I read small files there is no problem, but when I read text files too large I get an OutOfMemoryError. Reading similar problems change my text, and now use AsyncTask to read the file, but even so I get the same error.

This is my code:

```
 private class MiTarea extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String > {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.show(); //Mostramos el diálogo antes de comenzar
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


                    if (carpeta_para_leer == "Textos"){
                        sdcard = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/" + carpeta_para_leer + "/");
                    }else{
                        sdcard = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Textos/" + carpeta_para_leer + "/");
                    }


                    //Get the text file
                    File file = new File(sdcard, nombre_texto + ".txt");
                    sizeInBytes = file.length();
                    currentBytes = 0;

                    //Read text from file
                    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                    nepe = new ArrayList<String>();


                    try {
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "Cp1252"));
                        String line;

                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            line.replaceAll("\t", " ");
                            line.replaceAll("\n", " ");
                            delimitadores = " ";
                            String[] hola = line.split(delimitadores);
                            for (int i = 0; i < hola.length; i++ ){
                                nepe.add(hola[i]);
                            }
                            currentBytes += (long)line.length(); //HERE I TRY TO UPDATE THE PROGRESSBAR
                            por =  (currentBytes * 50) / sizeInBytes;
                            publishProgress(porcent);
                            Log.d("DoINBackGround", "" + currentBytes + " Y EL TOTAL ES " + sizeInBytes);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {

                    }

                    Holmes1 =text.toString();
                   // delimitadores = " ";
                   // arrayHolmes1 = Holmes1.split(delimitadores);

        return Holmes1;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate (Integer... valores) {
        dialog.setProgress((int) ((int) (currentBytes * 100) / sizeInBytes));
        Log.d("LLAMADA A PROGRESSBAR", "TOTAL: " + sizeInBytes + " LLEVAS: " + currentBytes + " PORCENTAJE: " + currentBytes/sizeInBytes + " POR: " + por );
        if (dialog.getProgress() == 100){
            onPostExecute(1);
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer bytes) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And this the logcat:

```
11-30 17:21:45.332    6175-6324/ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 1787236-byte allocation.
11-30 17:21:45.449    6175-6324/ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:123)
            at ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida.EL_Entrenamiento$MiTarea.doInBackground(EL_Entrenamiento.java:1262)
            at ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida.EL_Entrenamiento$MiTarea.doInBackground(EL_Entrenamiento.java:1224)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-30 17:21:45.925    6175-6175/ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida E/WindowManager﹕ Activity ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida.EL_Entrenamiento has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405b43e0 that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida.EL_Entrenamiento has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405b43e0 that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
            at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
            at ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida.EL_Entrenamiento$MiTarea.onPreExecute(EL_Entrenamiento.java:1229)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
            at ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida.EL_Entrenamiento.onClick(EL_Entrenamiento.java:497)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9081)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Native Method)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 17:21:53.386    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:21:53.386    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:21:53.386    6325-6334/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:22:59.246    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:22:59.246    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:22:59.246    6325-6334/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:24:03.941    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:24:03.941    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:24:03.941    6325-6331/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:24:53.450    1255-6344/? E/GTalkService﹕ createConnection: missing account.authToken...
11-30 17:24:57.638    6402-6402/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.plus.provider.PlusProvider.a
11-30 17:24:57.865    6325-6330/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:24:57.865    6325-6330/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:24:57.865    6325-6330/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:25:03.372    1255-6412/? E/GTalkService﹕ createConnection: missing account.authToken...
11-30 17:25:04.474    6402-6415/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method axo.a
11-30 17:25:05.216    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:25:05.224    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:25:05.224    6325-6334/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:26:11.779    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:26:11.779    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:26:11.779    6325-6331/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:27:17.700    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:27:17.700    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:27:17.700    6325-6331/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:28:22.638    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:28:22.638    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:28:22.638    6325-6334/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:29:27.544    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:29:27.544    6325-6334/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:29:27.544    6325-6334/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:30:31.990    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:30:31.990    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:30:31.997    6325-6331/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:31:37.779    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:31:37.786    6325-6331/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:31:37.786    6325-6331/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:32:01.146    1114-1142/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f0
11-30 17:32:03.443    6540-6540/ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f0
11-30 17:32:08.341    6540-6540/ccv.checkhellsing.lecturarapida E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f0
11-30 17:32:08.982    6402-6543/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method aod.b
11-30 17:32:08.982    6402-6543/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method aod.c
11-30 17:32:08.990    6402-6543/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method aod.d
11-30 17:32:49.732    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:32:49.732    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:32:49.732    6657-6662/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:33:56.411    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:33:56.411    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:33:56.411    6657-6662/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:35:01.396    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:35:01.404    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:35:01.404    6657-6662/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:36:05.716    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:36:05.716    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:36:05.716    6657-6663/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:37:10.021    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:37:10.021    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:37:10.021    6657-6663/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:38:14.255    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:38:14.255    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:38:14.255    6657-6662/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:39:18.544    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:39:18.544    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:39:18.544    6657-6662/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:40:22.810    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:40:22.810    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:40:22.810    6657-6663/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:41:27.094    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:41:27.094    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:41:27.094    6657-6662/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:41:48.555    1255-6677/? E/GTalkService﹕ createConnection: missing account.authToken...
11-30 17:41:52.766    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:41:52.766    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:41:52.766    6657-6663/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:41:53.180    1255-6735/? E/GTalkService﹕ createConnection: missing account.authToken...
11-30 17:42:02.281    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:42:02.289    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:42:02.289    6657-6663/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:43:10.281    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:43:10.281    6657-6663/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:43:10.281    6657-6663/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
11-30 17:44:16.438    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 119, freeSpace() = 81, numRows = 4188
11-30 17:44:16.438    6657-6662/? E/CursorWindow﹕ not growing since there are already 4188 row(s), max size 1048576
11-30 17:44:16.438    6657-6662/? E/Cursor﹕ Failed allocating 119 bytes for text/blob at 4187,3
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the InputStreamReader class already that will read the file byte by byte. The problem is caused by the BufferedReader that can't support the bug files size.

Try setChunkedStreamingMode(1024) to chunk your data into specific size, so that you need not keep your entire file in the memory.

for more details: [Upload large file in Android without outofmemory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630430/upload-large-file-in-android-without-outofmemory-error)

Good luck.

Comment: Where I have to put it? @mohamed khalloufi

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647319/upload-files-by-post-to-server-outofmemory